# What is difference between spring boot JPA and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I want to know how Spring boot JPA used hibernate, Is there any relationship between Spring boot JPA and hibernate?
When we used boot jpa then simply we implements org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository interface and can write queries using function name which is matching with column name or can write custom queries, then what is the role of hibernate here? and how can we say that hibernate is the implementation of JPA in spring boot?

Answer (score 4):

- Spring Data JPA is Spring abstraction to JPA (Java Persistence API) with more easy to use methods alongwith the defaults defined in JPA Specification
- Hibernate on the other case is a JPA Implementation (JPA provider).

Spring Data cannot exist by itself and needs one or the other JPA Provider for implementation of the methods. For this reason, Spring Data JPA can work with any JPA provider but comes auto-configured with Hibernate by default.

So, all ORM features in Spring-data under the hood for entity management and query submission etc are still using Hibernate implementations.
Repositories just allow you to write queries on the fly which again are converted to base queries based on the datasource provider and default hibernate SQL Dialect.

You can also use Spring-Data with other JPA Providers like (Toplink, OpenJPA, Eclipselink) with configuration in the project.

Answer (score 0):

JPA is a specification and it needs an implementation to be used, you can not use JPA by own. Hibernate is one of the popular JPA providers, so it is an implementation of JPA. The goal of Spring Data is to reduce the amount of boilerplate code required to implement data access layers for various persistence stores and GenericDao implementation. Spring Boot is a framework to create microservices. If you use Spring as a framework the combination of Hibernate, JPA and Spring Data will be the best choice to communicate with the database.